# How can i describe buttons in matrix?

Tags: vb.net, button, matrix

I have a 16*16 matrix and I'm trying to define them as a matrix series in vb.net. Then i make some visual shows with this matrix like led shows.

---

```
    Dim n As Integer = 16
    Dim l As Integer = 16
    Dim x(n - 1, l - 1) As Integer
    Dim i, j, k As Integer
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        For j = 0 To l - 1
            For k = 1 To 256
                If j= k mod16 then
                buton(k) = x(i, j)
               end if 
            Next

        Next
    Next***
```

I try to apply an algorithm. But it doesn't work. How can i accomplish this? Thanks for your interests..

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are having. What do you want the code to do and what is the code actually doing?

Comment: Should the line **k(mod16)=j** be **j= k mod 16** and what is buton(k)? Have a look at this page to see what to include in your question. [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your interests. I mean 256 buttons must be component of x(15,15) matrix series.

Comment: button(k) thats not working of course. even i doesnt define by vb.net

Comment: So all you want the code to do is add the buttons to the array X? What are the names of the buttons? Do they start at Button1 end end at Button256 or something else?

Comment: yes i want to add whole butons to array x. buttons names start from button1 and end button256.

Comment: OK I'll get back to you shortly with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I wrote something like this a while ago - I've adapted it to your needs and it runs ok on my pc. You need to create you array X like this

```
Dim x(15,15) As Button
```

To fill the array with buttons, use this method..

```
Private Sub InitializeArray()

    Dim btnslist As New List(Of Button)
    Dim btnNum As Integer
    Dim btnName As String
    Dim splitButtonName() As String
    'add all the buttons to a list
    For Each btnControl As Object In Controls
        Dim btn As Button
        'get button number and add it to the list if it is >0 and <=256
        If TypeOf btnControl Is Button Then
            btn = CType(btnControl, Button)
            'get the button number
            splitButtonName = Split(btn.Name, "n")
            If CInt(splitButtonName(1)) > 0 And CInt(splitButtonName(1)) <= 256 Then
                btnslist.Add(btn)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'add the buttons to the matrix in the right order
    For i As Integer = 0 To 15
        For j As Integer = 0 To 15
            For k As Integer = 0 To 255
                btnNum = i * 16 + j + 1
                btnName = "Button" & btnNum.ToString
                If btnslist(k).Name = btnName Then
                    x(i, j) = btnslist(k)
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a shorter way of doing this, but I had this code already

Comment: If the answer works for you, please click the tick to accept it. Cheers! If it doesn't let me know and I'll have a look at it